# How can I use another qml file as delegate in a qml ListView when using C++ model?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to use a ListView with a delegate from another qml file. Using a qml model works, but now I am using a C++ model and only works if the delegate is declared on the same qml file of the view.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Rectangle {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 500

    ListView {
        id: myListView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: myModel
        delegate: MyDelegate {}
    }
}
```

**MyDelegate.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

ItemDelegate{
    id: myDelegate
    width: parent.width
    height: 50
    Rectangle{
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "gray"
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtQuick/qquickitem.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickview.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    ElementModel model;
    model.addElement(Element("first");
    model.addElement(Element("second");

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model);

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I tried using `import "MyDelegate.qml" as MyDelegate` in the main.qml, but it doesn't work.
How can I do it?

Thanks!

**[SOLVED]**

The `view.setSource` method needs to be called like this to detect the others qml files:

```
view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
```

Comment: If the file is in the same directory as main.qml, no import is needed. Just use `MyDelegate` directly.

Comment: if I do so I get this error: ```MyDelegate is not a type```

Comment: @Pau Are the .qml in the same qresource ?, show your .qrc

Comment: Yes, this is my .qrc:

<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>MyDelegate.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>